# How to confirm action (answer "Y") in gdb script?

Tags: debugging, gdb, breakpoints

I use gdb to debug my cpp code.
I set breakpoints in this way:

```
(gdb) break ParseDriver.cc:60
No source file named ParseDriver.cc.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y
Breakpoint 1 (ParseDriver.cc:60) pending.
```

To simplify setting breakpoints, I wrote a simple gdb script(named breakpoints.gdb), it simply contains only one line:

```
break ParseDriver.cc:60
```

I source this script in gdb terminal, but it failed.

```
(gdb) source ~/breakpoints.gdb
No source file named ParseDriver.cc.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) [answered N; input not from terminal]
```

It seems that we need to answer Y in script in order to set breakpoint.

So, how can I answer Y in gdb script ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [gdb: how to set breakpoints on future shared libraries with a --command flag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100444/gdb-how-to-set-breakpoints-on-future-shared-libraries-with-a-command-flag)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
(gdb) set breakpoint pending on
```

This will make gdb skip asking for confirmation, quote from [the docs](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html):

> This indicates that an unrecognized breakpoint location should
>   automatically result in a pending breakpoint being created.

Comment: @Vadim Can we make it default using .gdbinit file?

Comment: @EmptyData Yes, assuming your gdb is not extremely old