# Can gdb's "input not from terminal" messages be suppressed?

Tags: gdb

I have a `gdb` script that ends with the command `quit`.

When I run the script like this:

```
gdb -x foo.gdb target_program
```

The final output always has:

```
Quit anyway? (y or n) [answered Y; input not from terminal]
```

Is there a way to suppress either the entire message, or even just the part inside the `[]`?

```
[answered Y; input not from terminal]
```

Comment: Try first execute `set confirm off` in your foo.gdb

Comment: @skwllsp, That works! I'm not sure how I would have found that myself, although. I'll accept that answer if you post it as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try first execute

```
set confirm off
```

in your foo.gdb