# How do I force a breakpoint from .gdbinit?

Tags: gdb, breakpoints

When I set a breakpoint in my `.gdbinit` using:

```
b foobar
```

I get this:

```
Function "foobar" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) [answered N; input not from terminal]
```

Now the first line is understandable, because the function resides in a shared library. However, this defaults to *no*.

How do I force it to set the breakpoint in such a non-interactive scenario?

Comment: possible duplicate of [gdb: how to set breakpoints on future shared libraries with a --command flag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100444/gdb-how-to-set-breakpoints-on-future-shared-libraries-with-a-command-flag)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This can be done using `set breakpoint pending on`. From the [Setting Breakpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html) documentation:

> gdb provides some additional commands for controlling what happens when the `break` command cannot resolve breakpoint address specification to an address:
>
> `set breakpoint pending auto` - This is the default behavior. When gdb cannot find the breakpoint location, it queries you whether a pending breakpoint should be created.
>
> `set breakpoint pending on` - This indicates that an unrecognized breakpoint location should automatically result in a pending breakpoint being created.
>
> `set breakpoint pending off` - This indicates that pending breakpoints are not to be created. Any unrecognized breakpoint location results in an error.