# Qt-creator skipping breaking points in debugging mode

Tags: android, c++, qt, debugging, qt-creator

I am investigating [QField](https://github.com/opengisch/QField) application on QT-Creator 3.5.1 (Based on Qt 5.5.1). QT-creator is installed on Ubuntu 15.10 on VMWare machine on Windows 10.

The application compiles, builds and runs (on debug or release modes) perfectly.

However, to investigate the code more thoroughly, I need to be able to debug the source files, but I can not. I make sure that I am on "Debug" mode and that I hit "Start Debugging" button.

Qt-Creator keeps skipping the breaking points and continues to load the android app on my tablet and functions normally without any stopping.

Here is the .pro file

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
CONFIG += ordered
CONFIG += c++11

SUBDIRS += 3rdparty
SUBDIRS += src
```

I even added `CONFIG += debug` line as some suggested, but makes no difference.

Here is "Tools-->Option-->Build & Run-->Debuggers" screenshot:

[image]

I would like to be able to debug the code, but how ? please help.

Comment: May be, you should edit .gdbinit file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28769956/how-to-force-a-breakpoint-from-gdbinit

Comment: @mustafagonul thanks but your link didn't help much. It is a good knowledge but doesn't change the debugging behavior